# CordaのNetworkで単一の組織が複数のNodeを持つことはできますか？

Tags: java

CordaのNetworkで単一の組織が複数のNodeを持つことはできますか？

Comment: もしご存知なければ……なのですが、スタック・オーバーフローでは自己回答ができ、また推奨しています。もしご自身の知見を Q&A の形で残そうとされているのであれば、ぜひご利用ください。信用度が小さいうちは少し時間がかかりますが、ご辛抱ください。（同じアカウントが回答していることが多いことから推測したのですが、もし間違っていればご放念ください） https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordaでは1Node１アイデンティティーが基本的な考え方となります。アイデンティティーは部署単位で設定できますので、単一の組織において、複数の部署が各自Nodeを保有することが可能です。例えば金融機関であれば、貿易金融をしている部署と国内融資をしている部署は異なるので、別々にNodeを維持することになるかと思います。当然インストールするアプリケーションも異なってきます。